# Definition of co-dimension of vector subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $E$ is a vector space and $S\subset E$ is a linear subspace of $E$. We can define the codimension as follows: codim(S) = dim(E/S).

I have also seen the following: we say $S$ is finite codimensional if there exists a linear subspace $N$ with $E = S+N$ where $N$ is finite dimensional.

My question is, does $dim(N) = codim(S) or not?

Comment: No, because the dimension of $N$ is not uniquely specified by $E=S+N$.

Comment: What about the case where $S\cap N = \emptyset$?

Comment: Can't happen, since both contain zero.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks.